# Can I ever go back to making smaller games?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

It seems I've spoiled my fans with AAA titles and whenever I release something that didn't take 15 millions to make they start throwing rotten fruit at me. AAA games are nice and all, but they are so big it takes a lot of time to get to the fun part of the game - fiddling with sliders to create the perfect game. Can I ween my fans off blockbuster games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your games are measured next to your previous average. If you release large amounts of AAA games, your average will reflect that since they have a very high weight compared to small games. As such the answer is yes, but you would have to spam **a lot** small games, 5 or 6 for every decent AAA, more for your successful ones